# Migrate oracle data (.dmp file) to mongodb

Tags: oracle, mongodb

I have installed MongoDB on my Linux machine. Now i want to migrate my oracle DB to MongoDB. I have .dmp file of my oracle user which need to be imported in Mongodb.
I am not sure whether i can directly use mongoimport to import it or there is any tool available for this migration.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: That's not possible. The only tools that can read and process and Oracle dump file are the Oracle tools (`impdp` or the deprecated `imp`)

Answer (score 0):

We can import the oracle data with mongoimport. Just we need the table to be exported in .csv format. 
We can export oracle table in .csv format wih the help of toad or SQL developer.
Once we have .csv file ready, we can import it into our mongodb with mongoimport command.